# Input Data is specific format

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, validation

I have a column set to text (I could change this to number eventually).

I would like to set a validation message for inputting a set of 12 numbers separated by a dash (Total 13 characters) in the following format 123456-123456.

This information is normally copied from another site as a reference number. So the copied value will have a dash included.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: I am using SharePoint 2016 and I am mostly using the Classic Experience version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the column validation as shown below:

```
AND(
LEN([Text])=13,                  
MID([Text],7,1)="-",              
ISNUMBER(MID([Text],1,6)+0),      
LEN(TRIM(MID([Text],1,6)))=6,    
ISNUMBER(MID([Text],8,6)+0),      
LEN(TRIM(MID([Text],8,6)))=6
)
```

[image]
[image]

Result:

[image]

For detailed information, please refer to:

https://www.techmikael.com/2018/02/validating-number-format-in-sharepoint.html

Comment: Thanks very much that solved completely my issue